# How to arrange data for an Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a problem with working out how to get that data I need in a pivot table.

My source data is as follows:

```
<pre>
EMPLOYEE_ID|  Leave_Date   |  Month_Yr  |  Leave_Type  |  Leave_Days  |  AREA    |     Manager     |  Manager_Team_Size
120        |  15 May 2015  |  May 2015  |Sick          |  1           | Sales    | Martin Brent    |  21
120        |  16 May 2015  |  May 2015  |Sick          |  1           | Sales    | Martin Brent    |  21
127        |   9 May 2015  |  May 2015  |  Family      |  0.75        |  HR      | Sandy Gibson    |  7
125        |   1 June 2015 | Jun 2015   |  Annual      |  1           |  HR      | Sandy Gibson    |  7
132        |   2 June 2015 |  Jun 2015  |  Annual      |  1           | Cust Supp| Nigel Watts     |  12
120        |   1 June 2015 |  Jun 2015  |Sick          |  1           | Sales    | Martin Brent    |  21
121        |   5 June 2015 |  Jun 2015  |  Family      |  0.5         |  HR      | Sandy Gibson    |  8
125        |   1 June 2015 | Jun 2015   |  Annual      |  1           |  HR      | Sandy Gibson    |  8
132        |   3 June 2015 |  Jun 2015  |  Annual      |  1           | Cust Supp| Nigel Watts     |  14

</pre>
```

The Pivot table I am trying to create is about the managers.  I want to see which managers are getting a lot of leave taken in their area to try to highlight potential problem areas.

Notice how the number of staff in a manager's team can change from month to month.

The pivot has slicers where users can slice by Month (ie Apr 2015, May 2015, Jun 2015) and by area and by leave type AND they can select multiple values (ie May & Jun) or HR, Cust Supp and Sales or combinations thereof.

Eg say I have sliced the data to show Jun data for Annual leave for HR I would want to see:

```
<pre>
Manager      |   Days_per_member
Sandy Gibson |  =2/7 (0.29)
</pre>
```

If I have sliced the data to show May and Jun for Sales and Cust Support for all leave types, I should see:

```
<pre>
Manager      |   Days_per_member
Martin Brent |  =3/21 (0.14)
Nigel Watts  |  =2/((12+14)/2) = (0.15)
</pre>
```

Nigel Watts' team was 12 strong in May and then 14 strong in June.

I cannot work out how to present the data in such a way that we can compare managers using a metric "Total days leave"/"Team size" to give me a leave/person in their team.  I used a calculated field in my data but calculated field always SUMS the values.  You cannot use MAX or MIN or AVG which would be ideal.  So the leave_days total is right but the Team size total is added repeatedly and ends up being a multiple of the team size.  So I thought of showing the team size parameter in my data as a function of team size divided by leave instances.  Eg if the team size is 10, and there are 8 days leave taken by this team, the parameter becomes 10/8.  This works BUT if I pick 2 types of leave in the slicer, and let's say this gives me 15 days of leave, the parameter should be 15/10 but instead I get 15/20 (it sums up the team size twice).

If I have to, I can limit it that users can only slice one month at a time but it would be great if they could slice multiple leave types at least.

I am so sick of this issue I am no longer seeing straight and my brain has stopped functioning well.  I cannot seem to make the mental breakthrough to solve this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can only be done in a conventional Pivot Table by adding a column of data in your source table that contains a 1 in every row, then your calculated field would be:

```
(Leave_Days/Manager_Team_Size)*ColumnContainingOnes
```

This will correct for the fact that you have counted the manager team size multiple times.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this worked.  I am still tying to understand why but I am supremely grateful to you!  Thank you so much!